# Qt How to disable mouse scrolling of QComboBox?

Tags: qt, scroll, mouse, qcombobox

I have some embedded QComboBox in a QTableView. To make them show by default I made those indexes "persistent editor". But now every time I do a mouse scroll on top them they break my current table selection.

So basically how can I disable mouse scrolling of QComboBox?

Answer (score 12):

As I found this question, when I tried to figure out the solution to (basically) the same issue: **In my case I wanted to have a QComboBox in a QScrollArea in pyside (python QT lib).**

Here my redefined QComboBox class:

```
#this combo box scrolls only if opend before.
#if the mouse is over the combobox and the mousewheel is turned,
# the mousewheel event of the scrollWidget is triggered
class MyQComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, scrollWidget=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyQComboBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        self.scrollWidget=scrollWidget
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

    def wheelEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.hasFocus():
            return QtGui.QComboBox.wheelEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.scrollWidget.wheelEvent(*args, **kwargs)
```

which is callable in this way:

```
self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
self.frmScroll = QtGui.QFrame(self.scrollArea)
cmbOption = MyQComboBox(self.frmScroll)
```

It is basically [emkey08's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19382766) in the [link Ralph Tandetzky pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3242107/7128154), but this time in python.

Comment: This worked for me with a `QSpinBox` (replace `QtGui.QComboBox` with `Qwidgets.QSpinBox`), thanks!

Comment: For me an even better way is to call the event's `ignore()`.  This will pass the event to the parent so you don't have to explicitly designate who receives the scroll.

```    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasFocus():
            return QtGui.QComboBox.wheelEvent(self, event)
        else:
            event.ignore()

Answer (score 5):

The same can happen to you in a `QSpinBox` or `QDoubleSpinBox`. On [QSpinBox inside a QScrollArea: How to prevent Spin Box from stealing focus when scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821802/qspinbox-inside-a-qscrollarea-how-to-prevent-spin-box-from-stealing-focus-when) you can find a really good and well explained solution to the problem with code snippets.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to disable mouse wheel scroll by installing [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.2/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) on your QComboBox and ignore the events generated by mouse wheel, or subclass QComboBox and redefine [wheelEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcombobox.html#wheelEvent) to do nothing.

Comment: I also changed the combobox's focus policy to click. This helped too. Thanks!

Comment: But the QComboBox is STILL FOCUSED if I wheel over it. Why? How to prevent it? I want not to disable focus but only focus on wheel.

Answer (score 1):

c++ version of Markus ansver

```cpp
class FocusWhellComboBox : public QComboBox
{
public:
  explicit FocusWhellComboBox(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
    : QComboBox(parent)
  {
    this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
  }

  void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* e) override
  {
    if (this->hasFocus()) {
      QComboBox::wheelEvent(e);
    }
  }
};
```